# Trying to format output from a for loop into a label

Tags: c#

I'm sure there's a simple answer to this but I'm trying to make a header using a for loop. My variable `tipRate` is set at `.10` and `TIPSTESP` is `.05`. The for loop works fine with a `Console.WriteLine` command in a console app, but I'm trying to do this in a form. The output should be `.10  .15  .20 .25`. I'm not sure how to append the string to keep it from writing over the previous output.  Thanks in advance.

```
for (tipRate = lowRate; tipRate <= highRate; tipRate += TIPSTEP)
    lblTipHead.Text = String.Format( "{0,  8}", tipRate.ToString("F"));
```

Comment: If you're asking a question, then it is desirable to mark a post as an answer or give some feedback about whether you solved your problem or not.

Answer (score 1):

```
lblTipHead.Text += " " + String.Format( "{0,  8}", tipRate.ToString("F"));
```

Also, `lblTipHead.Text = String.Empty;` before the loop. However it's a better practice to create a string first (or a `StringBuilder` using `Append()` method), concatenate your values and then assign it to `lblTipHead.Text`, which will prevent unneeded form refreshing.

Let me know if that's helpfull.

Answer (score 0):

You are replacing the label text every time, use `+=` instead of `=`

```
lblTipHead.Text += " " + String.Format( "{0,  8}", tipRate.ToString("F"));
```

You should also probably clear the label text before running the loop, just to be sure you aren't appending unwanted data, this will clear the label `lblTipHead.Text = ""`

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `+=` to append to the current value of `lblTipHead.Text` rather than destructively assign to it - in other words...

```
lblTipHead.Text += String.Format( "{0,  8}", tipRate.ToString("F"));
```

...instead of:

```
lblTipHead.Text = String.Format( "{0,  8}", tipRate.ToString("F"));
```

With `+=`, the statement translates to:

```
lblTipHead.Text = lblTipHead.Text + String.Format( "{0,  8}", tipRate.ToString("F"));
```